# How to boot by default on Windows Boot Loader with UEFI?

Tags: windows, boot, uefi, bootloader

I have a problem with my bios which freezes everytime I would like to enter it so I cannot modify anything in it. I've aleady contacted the manufacturer, he is sorry but I have to buy another one. But except the bios, everything works fine so I am not planning to buy a new one.

In order to boot on windows I have to press F11 to enter into the UEFI menu and select Windows Boot Loader. If I do not enter the UEFI I get a black screen with the message: Reboot and select proper boot device.

In the devices list in the UEFI menu I have some unknown devices which may cause some problems.
I can access to the EFI shell by pressing ESC when my PC starts.

Can I boot on my windows 10 without entering the UEFI menu ?

**UEFI Menu**
[image: Menu]

**EasyUEFI**
[image: EasyUEFI]

**SOLUTION**
I created a new entry like this:

[image: New entry]

I put the new entry on top of the boot order list shown previously and now my pc boots directly on my windows installation.

Comment: Questions absolutely should NOT contain the solution, that should be reserved for an answer.

Comment: @daam - I am not going to submit an answer, by removing your solution from your question, that’s a task only you can accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system was missing a boot entry for Windows.  You can add it with:

`bcdedit /set '{bootmgr}' path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`

This will create the NVRAM entry and add it to the first (default) position as described in the Microsoft documentation [BCD System Store Settings for UEFI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcd-system-store-settings-for-uefi).

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set BIOS options from Windows. But not many manufactures provides Tools to do so.

For Dell as Example: https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/sln310422/configuring-the-bios-using-the-dell-client-configuration-utility-dccu?lang=en

Or your use PowerShell to do so...
http://www.systanddeploy.com/2019/03/list-and-change-bios-settings-with.html

If this is not possible, than you can use Tools like [EasyUEFI](https://www.chip.de/downloads/EasyUEFI-letzte-Freeware_66456619.html) [bcedit](https://serverfault.com/questions/714337/changing-uefi-boot-order-from-windows) or the linux tool [efibootmgr](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/efibootmgr/)